# Get all invoices from QuickBooks

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am looking for a simple way (web service, API call, etc.) to simply get all upcoming invoices from Quickbooks Online Edition. Any easy way to achieve?  I'm looking for a relatively high level abstraction.

Note:  I am willing to disable authentication to avoid having to deal with certificates, etc. Just looking for a simple solution.

Comment: Is this a one-off thing you're looking to do, or are you looking to build a sustainable, ongoing process that does this?

Comment: Also- is this a SaaS app that you're building, or something custom/one-off for just a single QuickBooks Online company?   (Intuit makes two APIs available, but you can only use the nice friendly one if you're a SaaS application)

Comment: One-off.  All I am trying to do is get a list of due dates and client names from all my upcoming invoices.  One-off for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register your application with Intuit here: https://appreg.intuit.com/

Register with:

- Target Application: QBOE
- Environment: Production
- Application Type: desktop

Go to this URL in a browser (substitute your own application ID into the URL):
https://login.quickbooks.com/j/qbn/sdkapp/confirm?appid=YOUR-APPLICATION-ID-HERE&serviceid=2004&appdata=1

When prompted, make sure you TURN LOGIN SECURITY OFF by choosing the "No. Anyone who can log into [Application Name] can use the connection." option.

You'll get a connection ticket at the end of the process. Save it somewhere safe.

Write a program to send this HTTP body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?> 
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonDesktopRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2009-10-09T07:10:10</ClientDateTime> 
            <ApplicationLogin>application login goes here</ApplicationLogin> 
            <ConnectionTicket>connection ticket goes here</ConnectionTicket> 
            <Language>English</Language> 
            <AppID>application id goes here</AppID> 
            <AppVer>1</AppVer> 
        </SignonDesktopRq> 
    </SignonMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

To Intuit's server at:
https://webapps.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway

You'll get back a session ticket.

Write a program to send this HTTP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<?qbxml version="6.0"?> 
<QBXML> 
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonTicketRq> 
            <ClientDateTime>2006-09-20T15:49:26</ClientDateTime> 
            <SessionTicket>session ticket goes here</SessionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language> 
            <AppID>application id goes here</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer> 
        </SignonTicketRq> 
    </SignonMsgsRq> 
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError"> 
        <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="2"> 
            <MaxReturned>10</MaxReturned>
        </InvoiceQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

To that same URL.

The response will be a bunch of invoice data, in XML format.

Refer to the OSR when you need more details on syntax for qbXML requests:
http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

You can find some C# sample code here:
http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_csharp#c_net_sample_code_for_quickbooks_online_edition

IMPORTANT NOTE FOR OTHER PEOPLE READING THIS POST: This should only be used for one-off/custom type applications. IF YOU'RE BUILDING A SOFTWARE AS A SERVICE APPLICATION and trying to allow your end-users to sync their own QuickBooks data with your application, then you should look at IPP/IDS instead of the above qbXML example. http://developer.intuit.com/

Comment: What does the request ID stand for?  Also, is there a way to filter by dates like I asked or would you suggest getting them all back and just querying in memory?  Thanks!

Comment: It's a unique request ID you can send to keep track of the requests/responses you're sending receiving. There's a full page on it's use in the QuickBooks SDK PDF- but for QuickBooks Online you can just hard-code it or leave it out, as it won't matter for QuickBooks Online. Regarding filtering by dates... note my comment above: "Refer to the OSR when you need more details on syntax for qbXML requests:"   Open it up, check off "OE" on the left, uncheck "US", and choose "InvoiceQuery" from the "Select Message" drop-down at the top.

Comment: I must still be missing something because I can't seem to figure out a way to filter by Due Date.  It seems to allow other dates (such as last modified date), but I don't see a way to filter by Due Date and it's forcing me to filter after I get the data back, which I'd like to prevent if possible (in memory).  Any help would be great.  Thanks again.

Comment: QuickBooks Online *does not support* filtering by DueDate. If you want to filter by DueDate, you'll have to filter it in your own app, not via the API.